# Stuck Inside of Loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell, loops

Just making a silly program to work on my Powershell skills. The outer do...while works. I have even gotten the inner do...while to work, however instead of breaking both loops when the inner loop has been satisfied, it goes back to "Are you in a hurry? y/n:"
I have tried moving the break(s) around to various different spots in the code and I have tried labels. Nothing seems to give me the results I am looking for.
I understand there are probably ways a million times better to write this code and eventually I will look for ways to optimize. Right now, I am just trying to write the code in the way my mind works and to solve the problem - that is to say, no code rewrites please... unless what I am trying to do is impossible.

```
$resultArray = @("go", "not go")

# give result
$result = $resultArray | Get-Random

# text results to jason

# check if in hurry

do{
while ($get_in_hurry = read-host "Are you in a hurry? y/n:"){

# if in hurry, jump to spin
if ($get_in_hurry -eq "y") {
    Write-Host "You seleted you are in a hurry."
    Write-Host "My suggestion is to" $result "to poker with Jason tonight."
    break
}

# if not in hurry ask questions
elseif ($get_in_hurry -eq "n") {
    Write-Host "You seleted you are NOT in a hurry."
    # check mood
    do{
    while ($get_mood = read-host "Are you in a good mood? y/n:") {

    # if not in good mood, adjust percentage, and spin
    if ($get_mood -eq "n") {
        Write-Host "You seleted you are not in a good mood."
        Write-Host "Write something funny"
        $resultArray += "not go", "not go", "not go", "not go", "not go", "not go", "not go", "not go"
        Write-Host "My suggestion is to" $result "to poker with Jason tonight."
        break
    }

    # good mood, adjust percentage
    elseif ($get_mood -eq "y") {
        Write-Host "You seleted you are in a good mood."
        break
    }

    # if mood not yes or no, request yes or no
    else {
        Write-Host "Please speak in english. Are in a good mood? y/n:"
    }

    }

# gone to poker in last month, adjust percentage
# jason ask to go in last two weeks, adjust percentage
# did you go, adjust percentage
# do math

    }
    while (($get_mood -eq $null) -or ($get_mood -eq ""))
    }


# if hurry not yes or no, request yes or no
else {
    Write-Host "Please speak in english. Are in a hurry. y/n:"
    # save variable text to jason to update application to give better response to any funny answers that may be given
}
}


}
# if hurry null, request yes or no
while (($get_in_hurry -eq $null) -or ($get_in_hurry -eq ""))
```

Comment: Just a quick overlook ... you use a variable definition as condition in your 2nd and 3rd `while` condition. That's not going to work as you may expect it to. 

Comment: Try this to see what I mean: `if($get_mood = read-host "Are you in a good mood? y/n:"){'yes'}else{'no'}`

Comment: I started with just the "hurry" loop. Once I got that working as expected (prompting again on null & non 'y' / 'n' responses and doing math/breaking the loop, aka stopping the application in this case, on 'y' / 'n' responses), I then nested the "mood" loop under a 'n' response. I tried using the same formula I used for the "hurry" loop, since it seemed to work.
I want to try your suggestion. Not quite sure where you want me to insert it and/or what I would need to comment out.

Comment: The idea is to just keep nesting the next question under the "correct" responses. I am sure once I put together what you are trying to show me I'll see this approach is not feasible, but right now I am not making the connection. Appreciate all of your help!

Comment: Do not insert the snippet I suggested anywhere!!!! Run it as it is and answer once with `y` and once with `n`. Then you may get what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell has a little-used feature that allows you to *label* loops and then  jump to those labels from nested loops to either *break out of* (`break`) or *resume* (`continue`) the target loop.

Here's a simplified example (using just *one* label, but you're not limited to that):

```
:toplevel while ($get_in_hurry = Read-Host "Enter something (just Enter exits)") {
  while ($get_mood = Read-Host "Back to outer loop (y) or exit (n)?") {
    if ($get_mood -eq 'y') { 
      continue toplevel # *Resume* (continue with) the outer loop.
    } else {
      break toplevel    # *Break out of* the outer loop.
    }
    Write-Warning 'Invalid input. Please try again.'
  }
}

'Continuing after top-level loop.'
```

Note that even though the label is *defined* with a leading `:` (e.g. `:toplevel`), on *referencing it* the leading `:` must be *omitted* (e.g. `break toplevel`) - if you accidentally use `:` (e.g.
<del>`break :toplevel`</del>), the label is *ignored*; allowing optional use of `:` to avoid this pitfall is the subject of [GitHub issue #5724](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5724).

See also the docs:

- [Using a labeled `break` in a loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Break?view=powershell-7.4#using-a-labeled-break-in-a-loop)
- [Using a labeled `continue` in a loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Continue?view=powershell-7.4#using-a-labeled-continue-in-a-loop)